# Android Obtain all the children that a Layout has (Including Sub-childs)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, kotlin

Basically what im trying to do is create a function that has a **recursive calling**, so i can obtain all the RadioButtons, Buttons, FAB, TextView, and even others **SubViews** ( *LinearLayouts, RelativeLayouts, FrameLayout, ViewGroup* ). Right now i can obtain all the Layouts but when i wanna access the subcontent of those **subViews** those values never return...

```
var contentList = ArrayList<String>()

fun ManageView(viewGroup: ViewGroup, action: String, context: Activity){
    try {
        loop@ for (i in 0 until viewGroup.childCount) {
            var child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i)
            contentList.add(context.applicationContext.resources.getResourceEntryName(child.id))
            when (child) {
                is ViewGroup->{
                    ManageView(child,"vacant",context)
                }
                is RadioGroup -> {
                    contentList.add(context.applicationContext.resources.getResourceEntryName(child.id))
                }
            }
        }
        println("TOTAL OF ELEMENTS: " + contentList.size)
        contentList.forEach { list ->
            println("Data:  " + list)
        }
    }catch (exception: Exception){
        println("Houston we have a layout problem")
    }
}
```

and the values that i got are:

```
07-01 07:35:40.543 30090-30090/com.epictech.epiccab_driver I/System.out: TOTAL OF ELEMENTS: 18
Data:  framePrice
Data:  lblRate
Data:  viewInclude
Data:  layoutPaidHired
Data:  viewSeparator
Data:  idPaidSign
Data:  txtPaidResult
Data:  viewSeparatorRight
Data:  containerHiredDetails
Data:  layoutHiredPays
Data:  viewSeparatorPaidRight
Data:  frameTripRateInfo
07-01 07:35:40.544 30090-30090/com.epictech.epiccab_driver I/System.out: Data:  fragment_fragment_trip_info
    Data:  frameContainer
    Data:  layoutDriverData
    Data:  menu
    Data:  layoutFAB
    Data:  layoutSpeedometer
```

However in my xml i got a lot of Content that has a mix of FrameLayout, Relative and Linear. This is an example:

**MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.epictech.epiccab_driver.UI.MainActivity"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/framePrice"
        android:layout_width="510dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layoutDriverData">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblRate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_title_rate" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/viewInclude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblRate"
            layout="@layout/fragment_paid_hired" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameTripRateInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/framePrice"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_hired_trip_info" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameTripRateInfo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layoutDriverData">
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDriverData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu">
        <include
            layout="@layout/card_driver_status"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <include
            layout="@layout/menu_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutSpeedometer"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <include
            layout="@layout/fab_map"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSpeedometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the **MenuLayout** that **MainActivity** include

**MenuLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayouTripInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/fragment_trip_info" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewSeparatorTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayouTripInfo"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/menuGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparatorTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColor"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerPadding="7dip"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnStartTrip"
            style="@style/RadioButtonState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:text="@string/start_trip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnAddToll"
            style="@style/RadioButtonState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:text="@string/add_toll" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnAddExtras"
            style="@style/RadioButtonState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:text="@string/add_extras" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnOffDuty"
            style="@style/RadioButtonState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:text="@string/off_duty" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="9dp"
            android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutEmail"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/email"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_black_1000"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <com.epictech.epiccab_driver.Helper.Notification.CounterTextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="22dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:ctv_rounded_background_color="@color/md_red_600"
                    tools:text="99+" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:backgroundTint="?attr/primaryTextColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:contentDescription="@string/configurations" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnEndShift"
            style="@style/RadioButtonState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14285714"
            android:text="@string/end_shift" />

    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me what im doing wrong...

Thanks for all the support!!

Comment: Are you trying to get all the views?

Comment: Yeah, all the views and the content that those views has ( EditText, InputText, RadioButton, etc )

Comment: From your example you're collecting only RadioGroup so I added an answer for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To collect all the `RadioButton` views(as specified in your example) just change your code as follows. To collect more types put them in the same `when` block:

```
var contentList = ArrayList<String>()
fun ManageView(view: View, action: String, context: Activity) {

    try {
        // if you want all the views then add elements to the list without any when
        when (view) {
            is RadioGroup -> {
                loop@ for (j in 0 until view.childCount){
                    val child = view.getChildAt(j)
                    contentList.add(context.applicationContext.resources.getResourceEntryName(child.id))
                }
            } 
            //add more cases here to collect more types 
            // all the view types that you'd like to collect must be put here
        }
        println("TOTAL OF ELEMENTS: " + contentList.size)
        contentList.forEach { list ->
            println("Data:  " + list)
        }
        if (view is ViewGroup) {
            loop@ for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
                val child = view.getChildAt(i)
                when (child) {
                    is ViewGroup -> {
                        ManageView(child, "vacant", context)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (exception: Exception){
        println("Houston we have a layout problem")
    }
}
```